# Taking Value of dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

After using inner joins and fetching data from 3 tables I want to show course names that are assigned to Miss Jennifer whise `Tchr_ID` is 4 , `ddlcourse` is `dropdown list` id

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    SELECT 
        Course.Course_name, 
        Tchr_course_ID 
    FROM Course 
    INNER JOIN CourseOffering 
        ON Course.Course_ID=CourseOffering.Course_ID 
    INNER JOIN Tchr_Course 
        ON Tchr_Course.Course_offer_ID=CourseOffering.Course_offer_ID 
    where Tchr_Course.Tchr_ID = 4", conn);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

ddlcourse.DataSource = dr;
ddlcourse.Items.Clear();
ddlcourse.DataTextField = "Course_name";            
ddlcourse.DataValueField = "Tchr_course_ID";
ddlcourse.DataBind();
```

After fetching I am showing dropdown `textfield` as course name and I am applying `datavaluefiled` as `tch_Course_ID` because when user will select the course , its `tchr_course_ID` will be saved in db. to save id I am using `ddlcourse.SelectedItem.Value` but this gives me error in my insert statement about foreign key. It is not taking value of selected course. Why? and how can I correct it?

These tables are involved in it..

- **Course table:**(which have courses list in it) ==>
  (Course_ID,Course_name)
- **CourseOffering table:** (which have record that these courses are
  offered this semester) ==> > (Course_offer_ID, Course_ID)
- **Tchr_Course table:** (which have record that this course is assigned to
  this teacher) ==> (Tchr_course_ID, Course_offer_ID, Tchr_ID)
- **Profile table:** (simple contains teacher record) == >
  (Tchr_ID,NAme,Email)

Comment: please tell the table in which you want to insert ?

Comment: This is basically a lecture uploading system in which teacher has to first choose a course then she has to upload a file. So the table in which Lecture file is being inserted or tchr_Course_ID is being inserted is..

Lecture (Lecture_ID,Tchr_Course_ID,LEcture_File)

Comment: please do verify does the tch_course_id exists in tch_course_table ?

Comment: Id does exists in table but insert statement is still giving me error..

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectedValue` instate of using `SelectedItem.Value` since ur `ddlcourse` has `DataValueField` as `Tchr_course_ID` hence only `SelectedValue` gives u required result for `Tchr_course_ID`.

Comment: I did what you said but this error is still coming

"SQL Execution failed. The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Lecture_Tchr_Course". The conflict occurred in database "SproTrack", table "dbo.Tchr_Course", column 'Tchr_course_ID'.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @user3005601 dubbuge the code and check what `SelectedValue` has and same value present in table `Tchr_Course`

Comment: Ya!! ddlcourse.SelectedValue is giving 0(zero) while it should select tchr_course_id of selected course... Why is it happening?